# How to set minimum percentage width of View in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

I have two `Button`s organized in a row in a `ContraintLayout`.  By default, I need them to be evenly distributed each taking 50% of the `ConstraintLayout` width (easy enough with a vertical `Guideline` set to 50%):

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  ...
  
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/secondaryButton"
      style="@style/Button.Secondary"
      android:text="Secondary Button"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/primaryButtonBarrier"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/detail" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/primaryButton"
      style="@style/Button.Primary"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:text="Primary Button"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/middleGuideline"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/detail" />

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/middleGuideline"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
      android:id="@+id/primaryButtonBarrier"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:barrierDirection="start"
      app:constraint_referenced_ids="primaryButton, middleGuideline"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/detail" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Desired behavior (currently achieved programmatically with code snippet below):**

I also need to support "overflow" text in the primary `Button` on the right.

[image]

So, if I have a larger amount of text, the `Button` width will push past the 50% guideline.  I've tried using `app:layout_constraintWidth_min`, but it doesn't take a percentage (`wrap` or `dimen`).

The best solution I can come up with is setting the `Button` width to `wrap_content` and then the min width programmatically after the `ConstraintLayout` has been measured:

```
doOnLayout { constraintLayout -> 
    val layoutParams = primaryButton.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    layoutParams.matchConstraintMinWidth = constraintLayout.measuredWidth / 2
    primaryButton.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

I feel like there has to be a combo of settings here that I'm missing to achieve this.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you update your question with UI..  like which UI you need to achieve using ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Updated to be more clear 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do what you want that I know of with any standard XML code and the standard *ConstraintLayout* attributes. You might be able to do something with a nested layout, but, in general, that should be avoided with *ConstraintLayout*. I think that the way you devised is probably going to be the way to go.

However, if you want to do this all in XML, you could create a shadow button that is a replica of the primary button in all aspects (position, style, text, etc.) except that it is invisible. A barrier can then ride to the left of the shadow button and the center guideline. The visible primary button can now be constrained to the barrier since the barrier is not dependent upon the primary button. The primary button will at least be 1/2 the width of the *ConstraintLayout* but can expand beyond.

A second approach would be to create a custom view for the primary button. This custom view can implement an attribute that specifies a minimum width for the button based on the width of the *ConstraintLayout*.

**ButtonMinWidthOfParent.kt**

```
class ButtonMinWidthOfParent @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : MaterialButton(context, attrs) {

    private var minWidthOfParent = 0f

    init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ButtonMinWidthOfParent,
            0, 0
        ).apply {
            try {
                minWidthOfParent = getFloat(R.styleable.ButtonMinWidthOfParent_minWidthOfParent, 0f)
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    override fun getSuggestedMinimumWidth(): Int {
        return maxOf(
            super.getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
            ((parent as ViewGroup).measuredWidth * minWidthOfParent).toInt()
        )
    }
}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ButtonMinWidthOfParent">
        <attr name="minWidthOfParent" format="float"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**activity_main**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondaryButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Secondary Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/primaryButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/detail" />

    <com.example.secondarybutton.ButtonMinWidthOfParent
        android:id="@+id/primaryButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Primary Button that is a little bit longer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/detail"
        app:minWidthOfParent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/middleGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

There are undoubtedly other ways, but the XML way has the advantage of being a pure XML implementation with a *little* trickery while the custom view is a more standard way to extend view capabilities.

Comment: My issue is if I have text for the primary button `"Primary Button the is much longer"`, I need the width to expand past 50% and push the secondary button to the left.